# How to build a database that stores huge data while no need of frequent query?

Tags: database-design

We want to separate our data into fresh data and history data. History data is rarely used so we decide to move them to a specific database that stores huge data while no need of frequent query nor very good speed.

What kind of database is most suitable for this case?

Comment: Why not keep it in your existing database and move the data e.g. into a tablespace on a cheap (but huge) harddisk?

Answer (score 0):

I might consider below option if it is in Mysql.

1. Table will be partitioned by RANGE weekly.
2. On Master keep latest week's partition. And drop earlier partitions in below way.

> ```
>   a). set sql_log_bin=0; #Set local session to not log into binlog.
>
>   b). alter table drop partition OLD_PARTITION_NAME;
>
>   c). exit;
> ```

3. On Slave keep old data.
4. Set this kind of automated/manual job every week to drop old partition on Master.
5. You might have to once verify the selects going on Master.

Comment: You should mention which DBMS you are talking about